# A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. in react-native and give some byte code as an error

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bytecode

After creating the project when i run the react-native app,

> it gives me this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 142
 Exception Details:
   Location:
     com/android/build/gradle/internal/pipeline/VariantInfoImpl.<init>(Lcom/android/build/gradle/internal/scope/VariantScope;)V @200: goto
   Reason:
     Error exists in the bytecode
   Bytecode:
     0x0000000: 2b12 3cb8 0034 2a2b b900 4201 0059 1244
     0x0000010: b800 47b6 004d b900 5201 002b b900 5401
     0x0000020: 0059 1256 b800 472b b900 4201 0059 1244
     0x0000030: b800 47b6 005a c000 5c59 125e b800 47b9
     0x0000040: 0061 0100 5912 63b8 0047 2bb9 0042 0100
     0x0000050: 5912 44b8 0047 b600 6759 1269 b800 47c0
     0x0000060: 006b 4d3a 0e3a 0d36 0c3a 0b03 3e2c 3a04
     0x0000070: bb00 6d59 2c10 0ab8 0073 b700 76c0 0078
     0x0000080: 3a05 0336 0619 04b9 007c 0100 3a07 1907
     0x0000090: b900 8101 0099 0036 1907 b900 8501 003a
     0x00000a0: 0819 0519 08c0 0087 3a09 3a0f 0336 0a19
     0x00000b0: 0959 1289 b800 47b9 008a 0100 3a10 190f
     0x00000c0: 1910 b900 8e02 0057 a7ff c619 05c0 0090
     0x00000d0: 3a0f 190b 150c 190d 190e 190f c000 6bb8
     0x00000e0: 0096 2bb9 0042 0100 5912 44b8 0047 b600
     0x00000f0: 5ac0 005c 5912 5eb8 0047 b900 9801 00b7
     0x0000100: 009a b1
   Stackmap Table:
     full_frame(@142,
{UninitializedThis,Object[#62],Object[#107],Integer,
Object[#107],Object[#120],Integer,Object[#126],Top,Top,Top,
UninitializedThis,Integer,Object[#169],Object[#same_frame(@203)


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development 
environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-
started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag 
for more details.

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -
PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

I have changed the

> classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1") to 3.4.2

It didn't work. i can't understand the problem. Need support. I have re-installed the modules but it gives the same issue.

Below is my path variable...

[image: Environment Variables]

> System variables

[image: System variables]

Comment: this problem is killing me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By Changing The SDK version, I have fixed my issue... and some other have suggested the same thing.

My jdk1.8.0_20 was not working. So i have just changed the jdk to jdk-12.0.2. I don't know if it is correct or not.

This question is related to some other question but i could not find it then...

1. [Scala build crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628310/scala-build-crashed)

> Problem was in minor JDK version. Scala 2.12 require's newer version of JDK then 1.8.0_111. So after JDK upgrade everything work.

i wish it might help some.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using npx @react-native-community/cli doctor to get the exact problem, so you will be able to solve it easily